# Get Tax Amount In MiniCart

Tags: tax

I got the shipping address from the customer IP and set it to Quote.
And the total price includes the tax price.
But I don't know how to get the tax price.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $customerCart

$tax_amount = $this->customerCart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');
```

This returns the tax amount.